# How does PyOpenGL do it's magic with glGenBuffers?

Tags: python

I'm trying to shy away from the slow and high-overhead latebind frontend of PyOpenGL and specifically use the raw backend implementation...

The problem I'm having is I can't seem to figure out how the frontend turns the backend function `glGenBuffers( n, buffers )` into `buffers = glGenBuffers( n )`.

All I want to know is what do I pass to the `buffers` argument of the backend function??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some examples of creating one or multiple buffers using `glGenBuffers`. If you must use function calls like `glGenBuffers(n, buffers)`, you can either use ctypes directly or use PyOpenGL's `GLint`, which wraps up a ctypes data type.

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GL import *
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600), pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF) #initialize OpenGL

py_id = glGenBuffers(1) #typical way to generate a single index
c_id = ctypes.c_int() #using ctypes to generate a second index
glGenBuffers(1, c_id)
gl_id = GLint() #using GL wrapper to generate a third index
glGenBuffers(1, gl_id)
print py_id, c_id.value, gl_id.value #should print 1 2 3

n = 10
py_list = glGenBuffers(n) #typical way to generate multiple indices
c_list = (ctypes.c_int * n)() #using ctypes to generate multiple indices
glGenBuffers(n, c_list)
gl_list = (GLint * n)() #using GL wrapper to generate multiple indices
glGenBuffers(n, gl_list)
print py_list, list(py_list) #note the default is a numpy array!
print np.array(c_list), list(c_list)
print np.array(gl_list), list(gl_list)
```

As a side note, I am not sure what the benefit of doing this is. I doubt that the convenient wrapper around `glGenBuffers` is really so slow that the typical approach like `buffers = glGenBuffers(n)` should be avoided. I am really curious to know if this is a performance bottleneck for you. Hope this helps!

**Update:**
After your comment about the overhead of `__call__`, I figured I would test it out in timeit. Here is my code, with the results in seconds included next to each timed block:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GL import *
import pygame
import timeit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600), pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF) #initialize OpenGL

def test(func, repeats):
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    for i in range(repeats):
        func()
    elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
    print elapsed

def func1():
    py_id = glGenBuffers(1)

def func2():
    c_id = ctypes.c_int()
    glGenBuffers(1, c_id)

def func3():
    gl_id = GLint()
    glGenBuffers(1, gl_id)

def func4():
    n = 1
    py_list = glGenBuffers(n)

def func5():
    n = 1
    c_list = (ctypes.c_int * n)()
    glGenBuffers(n, c_list)

def func6():
    n = 1
    gl_list = (GLint * n)()
    glGenBuffers(n, gl_list)

def func7():
    n = 100
    py_list = glGenBuffers(n)

def func8():
    n = 100
    c_list = (ctypes.c_int * n)()
    glGenBuffers(n, c_list)

def func9():
    n = 100
    gl_list = (GLint * n)()
    glGenBuffers(n, gl_list)

test(func1, 1000000)#4.12597930903
test(func2, 1000000)#5.2951610055
test(func3, 1000000)#5.17853478658
test(func4, 1000000)#4.06362866711
test(func5, 1000000)#3.45259988251
test(func6, 1000000)#3.43240155354
test(func7, 1000000)#4.128162421
test(func8, 1000000)#3.57384911559
test(func9, 1000000)#3.52125689729
```

From these results, it looks like the number of buffers you are generating does not make too much of an impact, so it should always be treated as a list, even when n=1. Not really sure why that is the case, perhaps some sort of conversion is going on behind the scenes in that case. Oddly enough, it looks like GLint() performs better than using ctypes directly which also makes no sense to me. Either way, the pure python version does perform the slowest, and I imagine that for other more complex OpenGL functions, the difference can be even greater!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, yes it is, especially on my single-core 4GB laptop... but instead of simply telling, I should be showing time results between the backend and frontend implementations... after analyzing the extremely large `__call__` wrapper applied to functions like that, I can already tell you there WILL be a noticeable speed boost with the backend function.

Comment: Ok, so I attempted to use timeit to determine if there indeed was a performance difference and it looks like you are right. I am updating my post with this information. Overall, the results appear to be that you should always treat the buffers argument as a list, even when n=1 buffer!

Comment: I still haven't gotten around to my results as I'm still porting the code from the iqm GPU demo, but that one I never would've guessed... also the reason GLint performs better for you is because the dot operator is slow... try importing c_int and calling that directly. (It helps to know the dot operator is simply a call to `__getattribute__`)

Comment: You were right, the dot operator was slowing it down. I did not know that could be a source of lost performance, but it makes sense since you are wasting time looking up c_int otherwise.

Comment: Btw, another small detail I wanted to point out... if you're not using numpy, the returned array is a (I think) ctypes base implemented by the array interface of PyOpenGL... (I've found many cases where numpy seems to perform no better than using python lists, and tend to stick with the far more performative native array.array type)

Comment: Interesting. In that case I probably need to switch over all of my VBOs from numpy arrays to the OpenGL.arrays.vbo class for my engine!

Comment: I actually advise against that class because it uses ARB buffers... OpenGL's native glBindBuffer and glBufferData work just fine. I'm not sure if you can stumble across my pyASSIMP modern 3D viewer, which does just that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129764/discussion-between-user2588654-and-tcll).